# Абсолютные и относительные пути

Tags: php

Я подключаю в конструкторе класса класс из другого файла с помощью относительного пути. После чего я добавил в этом же файле тестовую переменную для отладки кода. Загрузил страницу и всё работает. После чего я создал экземпляр класса ApiSelfHelper в другом файле и сделал вызвал его. И у меня посыпались ошибки

[image: ошибка]

```
<?php
 class ApiSelfHelper{
    private $sql;

    public function __construct(){
        require_once '../../../nedv/vendor/dbhelper.php';
        $this->sql = new DbHelper();
    }

}
$test = new ApiSelfHelper();
$test->Authorization();

?>
```

Comment: если автозагрузку не юзаете, то объявите константу, указывающую на корень проекта, и стройте пути от нее. и require внутрь кода не пихайте.

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/file.php'`, например

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще теран прав, проблему можно решить введя константу обозначающую корень сайта и с помощью конкатенации добавлять к константы путь до файла.
В вашем случае переменная бы значение:

```
    define('DOM', 'E:\xampp\htdocs\nedv');
    require_once DOM.'../../../nedv/vendor/dbhelper.php';
```

Подробнее с константами можете ознакомиться на официальном сайте [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.php)